# CTRL+SHIFT+C/V not working in Terminal

Tags: command-line, 16.04, gnome-terminal

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I found today that my copy/paste commands don't work in the terminal. I've tried every solution I could find with a bit of googling, but nothing seems to help.

"Right click"->"paste" will paste fine into a terminal, but "right click"->"copy" doesn't seem to copy from the terminal.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be sure to enable Shortcuts in your gnome-terminal preferences:

[image]

Comment: Enabled. Still not working.

Comment: @AndrewWatson ok, try to reinstall it with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-terminal`

Comment: Just reinstalled. Still not working.

Comment: As you're a reputation 6 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!

Comment: Great solution, thanks Sylvain.
I performed 'do-release-upgrade' from 20.04-22.04 and lost the ability to Ctrl+Shift+C and Ctrl+Shift+V !
That was really frustrating and after much searching I found this solution :)

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem. Turned out that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> was taken by gnome-tweaks to change keyboard layouts.

If this is the case with you, go to gnome-tweaks (just type it in the terminal), go to
**Keyboard & Mouse > Additional Layout Options > Switching to another layout**.

**Ctrl+Shift** will be checked. Just uncheck it and it should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Great solution!